# How to update state using setTimeout in recompose?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

I wanted to learn recompose so I started with a simple component component:

```
const timer: React.SFC<MyProps | any> = ({ seconds }) => (
  <span>{ seconds }</span>
);
```

I'd like to somehow pass `seconds` to it using recompose, where it would increment each second.

```
let seconds = 0;
export default compose(
  withProps(() => ({ seconds })),
  pure,
)(Timer);
```

How can I properly increment `seconds` props so it is propagated to the component on props change? I tried adding recurrsive function with `setTimeout` after `let seconds` declaration but it doesn't propagate down to the component on change.

I ended up with this

```
let seconds = 0;

incrementSeconds();

function incrementSeconds() {
  seconds += 1;
  setTimeout(
    () => {
      incrementSeconds();
    },
    1000,
  );
}

export default compose(
  withProps(() => ({ seconds })),
  pure,
)(Timer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `withProps`, I would make use of `withState` and then update the state like

```
export default compose(
  withState('seconds', 'updateSeconds', 0),
  lifecycle({
     componentDidMount() {
         const { seconds, updateSeconds} = this.props;
         setTimeout(
            () => {
               updateSeconds(seconds + 1);
            },
            1000,
         );
     }
  }),
  pure,
)(Timer);
```

Comment: Recursion is missing but it helped. It works for me now, thanks!